# rate monotonic analysis

Tags: linux, kernel, real-time, scheduling, code-analysis

I am working on a project to validate the multithreaded execution of a rather large program using [rate monotonic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling). To perform the analysis I need the execution time of each time it runs as well as number of times it ran. In the end, the data will be analyzed to find an average period for each thread that runs. Are there any solutions to my problem of collecting this data? I have looked into [LTTng](http://lttng.org/) and [Intel vTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/) but there are some questions:

1.) Does LTTV/eclipse plug calculate the average execution time I need?

2.) Does Intel VTune work in a kvm virtual machine?

The development computer is a server that is currently running RHEL directly on the hardware (but with AMD processor), but will eventually be moved to a vm running on intel xeon processors.The software also has both c++ and java executables that run.

Comment: As far as I know RMA is used to test realtime systems. I'm just curios what kind of VM are you planning to use later, that is realtime? (to the best of my knowledge neither VMWare nor XEN is realtime)

Comment: There is no "realtime" VM being used. We are using VMWare. We are using VMs because we need to test realtime systems that need to communicate and coexist at the same time. The target system will run on COTS CPUs like the development server with a linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

The `perf` utility can be used to count and trace performance events in the KVM kernel module.

http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Perf_events#Recording_events

Use a command like this (use `sudo` if you aren't logged in as root):

```
# perf kvm --guest [kvm options] record -a -o my.perf.data
```

To report the results, like this

```
# perf kvm --guest report -i my.perf.data
```